# mysql - select if also is in other tables

Tags: mysql

i have 4 tables: table1, table2, table3, table4.

```
table1= user_id, username 
table2= tbl2_user_id, tbl2_name 
table3= tbl3_user_id, tbl3_name 
table4= tbl4_user_id, tbl4_name 
i want to select the users in table1 if they also are in one of: (table2 OR table3 OR table4). 

example: 
table1=user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, user6, user7, user8, user9, user10. 
table2=user2, user5, user7. 
table3=user3. 
table4=user4, user9.

[result of table1 select: user2, user3, user4, user5, user7, user9].
```

I tried this code and did NOT work:

```
select t1.username 
from table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2
            ON t1.user_id = t2.tbl2_user_id
    INNER JOIN table3 t3
            ON t1.user_id = t3.tbl3_user_id
    INNER JOIN table4 t4
            ON t1.user_id = t4.tbl4_user_id
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

INNER JOIN is not the correct way, that filters only when all 3 are met, you need a LEFT JOIN and a WHERE condition

A Left Join to not filter the query, and then a WHERE to see if any of them are valid

```
select t1.username 
from table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2
            ON t1.user_id = t2.tbl2_user_id
    LEFT JOIN table3 t3
            ON t1.user_id = t3.tbl3_user_id
    LEFT JOIN table4 t4
            ON t1.user_id = t4.tbl4_user_id
WHERE
   (
     t2.tbl2_user_id is NOT NULL OR
     t3.tbl3_user_id is NOT NULL OR
     t4.tbl4_user_id is NOT NULL
   )
```